# AWS Spring can't set object mapper

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, kotlin, jackson

im trying to set jackson serializer at spring MessageTemplate to send messages alredy formated using jacksonMapper and SQS/SNS, the problem is that it keeps sending messages unformated, even with notation @JsonProperty or @JsonFormat

here is my configs:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class AwsMessagingConfigurationLocal(
   @Value("\${cloud.aws.region.static}") val region: String,
   @Value("\${cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey}") val accessKey: String,
   @Value("\${cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey}") val secretKey: String,
   @Value("\${cloud.aws.endpoint}") val endpoint: String
) {

   @Bean
   fun notificationMessageTemplate(): NotificationMessagingTemplate {
       return NotificationMessagingTemplate(buildAmazonSNSAsync())
   }

   @Bean
   fun queueMessagingTemplate(): QueueMessagingTemplate {
       return QueueMessagingTemplate(buildAmazonSQSAsync())
   }

   @Bean
   fun simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(): SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory {
       val messageListenerContainerFactory = SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory()
       messageListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(buildAmazonSQSAsync())
       return messageListenerContainerFactory
   }

   @Bean
   fun queueMessageHandlerFactory(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): QueueMessageHandlerFactory {
       val messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
       messageConverter.objectMapper = objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())

       val queueMessageHandlerFactory = QueueMessageHandlerFactory()
       queueMessageHandlerFactory.messageConverters = listOf(messageConverter)
       queueMessageHandlerFactory.setArgumentResolvers(listOf(NotificationMessageArgumentResolver(messageConverter)))

       return queueMessageHandlerFactory
   }

   private fun buildAmazonSNSAsync(): AmazonSNSAsync {
       return AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
           .withEndpointConfiguration(AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, region))
           .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
           .build()
   }

   private fun buildAmazonSQSAsync(): AmazonSQSAsync {
       return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
           .withEndpointConfiguration(AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, region))
           .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
           .build()
   }
}
```

but when i send an object with LocalDateTime, even with @JsonFormat it keeps sending wrong format:

```kotlin
data class Blob(

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    val timestamp: LocalDateTime

)
```

i made this simple dispatch function to send messages through SNS(topic) and connected a queue to receive the responses.

```kotlin
class Dispatcher(
    private val private val notificationTemplate: NotificationMessagingTemplate
)

fun dispatch(blob: Blob) {
    val header = mapOf("randon" to "message")
    notificationTemplate.convertAndSend("topic", blob, header)
}
```

wanted result :

```
\"timestamp\"=\"2021-11-26T19:18:46.905505\"
```

current result :

```
"timestamp\":{\"nano\":913070000,\"year\":2021,\"monthValue\":11,\"dayOfMonth\":26,\"hour\":19,\"minute\":18,\"second\":46,\"month\":\"NOVEMBER\",\"dayOfWeek\":\"FRIDAY\",\"dayOfYear\":330,\"chronology\":{\"calendarType\":\"iso8601\",\"id\":\"ISO\"}}
```

i don't have any clue about what is happening.

PS. i tested SQS too, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching inside awspring, i found that the SimpleMessageConverter is set by default, after some research, i found the right way to set the custom mapper at sendAndConvert() function. here is the configurtions:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun notificationMessageTemplate(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): NotificationMessagingTemplate {
        // here we set the custom message converter
        val messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
        messageConverter.objectMapper = objectMapper
        // as we want to send it as a Json, we need to set the serialization to String
        messageConverter.serializedPayloadClass = String::class.java

        val notificationMessageTemplate = NotificationMessagingTemplate(buildAmazonSNSAsync())
        // here is where we set the proper message converter
            notificationMessageTemplate.messageConverter = messageConverter
        return notificationMessageTemplate
    }

    @Bean
    fun queueMessagingTemplate(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): QueueMessagingTemplate {
        val messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
        messageConverter.objectMapper = objectMapper
        messageConverter.serializedPayloadClass = String::class.java

        val queueMessageConverter = QueueMessagingTemplate(buildAmazonSQSAsync())
        queueMessageConverter.messageConverter = messageConverter
        return queueMessageConverter
    }
```

after setting this mappers, every notation will be working fine.

here is the result:

```kotlin
\"timestamp\":\"2021-11-29T17:46:52Z\"
```